# unable to scroll an image in tkinter

Tags: tkinter

I have an image that can assume variable sizes, and I want to display it in a window with scrollbars, to explore it.
I did the following

```
        connroot = Toplevel()
        connfr = Frame(connroot)
        conncv = Canvas(connfr, relief=SUNKEN)
        sbarV = Scrollbar(connfr, orient=VERTICAL)
        sbarH = Scrollbar(connfr, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        sbarV.config(command=conncv.yview)
        sbarH.config(command=conncv.xview)
        conncv.config(yscrollcommand=sbarV.set)
        conncv.config(xscrollcommand=sbarH.set)
        sbarV.pack(side=RIGHT, fill=Y)
        sbarH.pack(side=BOTTOM, fill=X)
        conncv.pack(side=LEFT, expand=YES, fill=BOTH)
        connfr.pack()
```

then at given events I display the image:

```
        photoconn = PhotoImage(file=tg)
        conncv.create_image(0,0, anchor=NW, image=photoconn)
        img.append(photoconn)
```

my problem: the image shown is cropped, BUT the scrollbars are "full", and there is nowhere to scroll to.
Yet I'm sure I read somewhere that the scrollbars have to have the frame as parents

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to tell the canvas widget what part of the large virtual canvas should be viewable. You do this by setting the `scrollregion` attribute of the canvas. Normally you pass in the result of the `bbox` method, which gives the bounding box of objects in the canvas. The special string `"all"` gives you the coordinates of a box in which all of the canvas objects can fit.

For example:

```
conncv.configure(scrollregion=conncv.bbox("all"))
```